# How to re-enable a checkbox in a listview with binding in WPF?

Tags: wpf

I have a multi-trigger for my IsEnabled and IsChecked property.  It is working well except that after the checkbox is disabled, it will not re-enable with code.  Here is the XAML:

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="lstRewardsEarned_ScrollChanged" Height="178" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,0,0,81" Name="lstRewardsEarned" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="327" SelectionMode="Multiple" Background="White" FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="16">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">

            <!-- bind content IsSelected to the ListViewItem IsChecked -->
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" />

            <!-- bind content IsEnabled to the ListViewItem IsEnabled -->
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Path=IsEnabled, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" />

            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Border x:Name="Border" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </Border>

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                            <!--Highlight if IsSelected and IsEnabled-->
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                                    <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Cyan"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                            </MultiTrigger>

                            <!--Remove highlight if is not Selected and IsEnabled-->
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>
                                    <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                            </MultiTrigger>

                            <!--Add a trigger to remove the highlighting if IsEnabled is changed to false-->
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

This is the code to re-enable the checkboxes:

```
For Each checkBox As CheckBox In lstRewardsEarned.Items
    checkBox.IsEnabled = true

    'This writes out false!
    Console.WriteLine(checkBox.IsEnabled)
Next
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take the UpdateSourceTrigger out of the IsEnabled and IsSelected property bindings?

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger.aspx)

> If you set the UpdateSourceTrigger value to Explicit, you must call
>   the UpdateSource method or the changes will not propagate back to the
>   source.

Comment: Thanks Matt.  I tried taking out UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit and it has no effect.  Should I raise an IsEnabled event or modify something else?